# Swift: Can I create an instance of a subclass with the the class properties referencing an instance of the class?

Tags: class, swift, subclass

In Swift, I am trying to create subclasses of a class which will add properties and methods that are specific to certain instances of the class.  I would like to initialize an instance of a subclass with an instance of the class, such that the class properties of the subclass instance actually refer to the class instance from which it initialized.  My goal is to be able to set a class property in the subclass instance, and have it also set the same property in the class instance from which it was initialized. I have not been able to find a way to create an initializer which accomplishes this, even if I set all the class properties to be the same for the subclass instance and the class instance.  The only way I have been able to do this is to add a variable to the subclass and set it to the class instance, but this is cumbersome. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an appropriate init like this:

```
class A {
  // ...
}
class B:A {
  init(clone:A) {
    // assign from the other object what needed
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That method appears to create an new instance of the class in the subclass and does not reference the original class instance.  Setting a property in the subclass does not appear to set the property in the originaal class instance.

Comment: You can simply save the instance `clone` in the new `B` instance as a (private) property.

Comment: I never could get this to work, any way I tried the new subclass instance would not point to the superclass instance from which it was initialized.  I worked around this by keep a var in my subclass and set it to the superclass initializing instance.  This makes the code a little less simple, but it works.